# Show Google Calendar in C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, google-calendar-api

I want to show my google calendar in my application's tabs. How can I do it?

```
private void tabPage6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //I  want to add the code in this tab
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `WeBrowser` control for this. Drag and drop a `WebBrowser` control from Tools, suppose name of the `WebBrowser` control is `webBrowser1` the use below code to open calendar

```
private void tabPage6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.com/calendar/");
        webBrowser1.Show();`
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response but why this message apprear "the name calendar does not exist in the current context" !
and i want u to take a look at this link -> https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet
thanks again :)

Comment: @BèlguesmiSémah bro I have just check it, try updated one

Comment: yes it worked now, thanks so much man ..
one more question please .. i want to add/delete/edit an event from the google calendar .. and maybe showing notifications too ..
any idea about that ??
anyway i'm very thankful for your help ;)

Comment: for edit delete or other manipulation you need to integrate google calendar api, you can take a look at this https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/